# Ограничение первичным ключом двух столбцов

Tags: sql, база-данных, many-to-many

Я создаю таблицу для связи M:M .

```
 create table if not exists user_musicType(
          user_id integer references users(id),
          musicType_id integer references music_types(id),
          primary key(user_id, musicType_id)
```

Первичный ключ, как я понимаю , у меня ограничивает существование двух одинаковых пар, однако он также не позволяет хранить одинаковые значения , например 2-2. Хотя у юзера с `id=2`  вполне может быть тип музыки с `id` так же `2`. Как сделать чтобы можно было хранить такие пары?

Answer (score 2):

Вы неправильно понимаете, ваш первичный ключ позволяет хранить такие пары.

`primary key(user_id, musicType_id)` означает, что должны быть уникальными пары значений. То есть вот такие значения добавить будет можно:

```
user_id  musicType_id
1        1
2        1
1        2
2        2
```

А добавить еще раз существующую комбинацию `(user_id, musicType_id)` - именно комбинацию - уже нет.

Comment: Почему тогда в базе они не появляются, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: В чем угодно, надо смотреть всю цепочку действий по добавлению. Если у вас пользователь работает через клиентское приложение, то там сначала формируется запрос, туда подставляются какие-то данные, потом они отправляются (или не отправляются) на сервер, сервер их вставляет (или не вставляет), выкидывает исключение (или не выкидывает), оно подавляется в клиентском приложении (или не подавляется), а еще в БД может быть триггер на таблице, и еще 100500 причин.

Comment: И кстати, если бы было нарушено ограничение целостности, база бы вам именно об этом сообщила. В сообщении об ошибке было бы что-то вроде `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

Comment: Разобрался.  Ошибка была в коде где я обрабатывал входящие музыкальные типы. Если такой уже есть , я не добавлял его в базу, а перешагивал к следующему. А надо было перед перешагиванием добавить его тек. пользователю.